# Evaluating $\iiint_{G}\exp(-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3})dV$ using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

Given $G=E\cap F$ with
$$E=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4z\}$$
and
$$F=\{(x,y,z)\mid3x^2+3y^2\leq z^2\}$$

I have to evaluate:
$$\iiint_{G}\exp(-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3})dV$$

Using spherical coordinates, I got
$$G=\{(\rho,\theta,\phi)\mid0\leq\theta\leq2\pi, 0\leq\phi\leq\pi/6, 0\leq\rho\leq4\cos\phi\}$$

However, since $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$, the first integral becomes
$$\int_{0}^{4\cos\phi}\exp(-\rho^3)\rho^2d\rho=\frac{1}{3}(-\exp(-64\cos^3\phi)+1)$$
and then, the second integral is
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\frac{1}{3}(-\exp(-64\cos^3\phi)+1)\sin\phi d\phi$$

My question is: how do I evaluate (using elementary functions) the following integral
$$\int\exp(64\cos^{3}\phi)\sin\phi d\phi$$

**PS: I'd also appreciate if someone could tell me that everything is right.**

Comment: @NinadMunshi I followed what J. Stewart did on his book, Example 4 from page 930, 7th edition. So I'm quite sure $E\cap F$ is correct.

Comment: But $z^2=3x^2+3y^2$ is a cone, not a paraboloid.

Comment: What you said makes sense! I was confused about the bottom but you are right. In that case consider flipping the order of integration to do $\phi$ first. This will make your integral two integrals split at $\rho=\sqrt{12}$ but it should be doable without special functions.

Comment: But how am I supposed to that? Because $\rho$ depends on $\phi$. Do I have to make it using the basic ideas of integral?

Comment: Draw a picture in a $\rho \phi$ plane with bounds $\rho = 4\cos\phi$ and $\phi=\pi/6$. From there it will be easy to see what your two sets of boundaries have to be and how to invert the equations properly. It may not work but doing this in cylindrical coordinates would be very difficult too.

Comment: @NinadMunshi just to let you know: I did what you said, but I got $\int x^3\exp(x^3) dx$ which is not evalueated using elementary functions. Anyway, I appreciate your help.